# Why does Shotwell have the X & Y positions inverted when using crop

Tags: 11.04, shotwell

When I try to crop an image with shotwell and select **Custom Crop**, the X and Y are inverted.

I think it should be like this: the first number is how long the image is (X) and the second how high it is (Y).

[image: photo is 7 wide 5 high, shown as 5 x 7]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

Cyrex -- Shotwell uses height x width as is standard for photo sizes, as fluteflute mentioned.  Currently, Shotwell limits the crop ratio to a series of pre-defined sizes for printing.

However, in the upcoming Shotwell 0.10 we've decided to remove that limitation.  In the meantime, you can always right click on the photo and select Open With External Editor to perform the crop in another program.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason then this is standard for [photo print sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_print_sizes). I guess Shotwell tries to maintain consistency with this.

Comment: Sorry did not understand are you saying that Shotwell only works for Photo print sizes? If yes does this include the Custom option in the bottom of the list?